# How to update a flash embed object in Ember?

Tags: flash, ember.js

```
    <object width="640" height="390"> 
    <param name="movie" {{bindAttr src="value"}} ></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
    <param name="playerapiid" value="main"></param>
    <embed {{bindAttr src="src"}} type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    allowscriptaccess="always"
    width="640" height="390"></embed>
    </object>
```

So I bound the attributes of where the embed file was but when the HTML updates to n values the embed object (a youtube video in this case) does not change. I can not find any guide on how to draw embed objects in an ember app.

Comment: I don't understand the question. When you change the src or value properties, these values doesn't update?

Comment: the values in the HTML update. But the video on the page stays the same.

Comment: I have answered the question. My example works for you?

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers you cannot update the src url of embed. To do this you need to remove the entire element, clone, change the src url, and append again.

Make this in embed is easy, just use the `view.rerender`, and the dom will be replaced with the new copy.

The only trick is: create a view that wrap the embed view. From the wrapper view, we call the `rerender`. So we don't lost the `srcChanged` observer in next calls.

The view implementation

```
App.VideoView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'video',
    embedView: Ember.View.extend({
        src: null,
        templateName: 'embed',
        srcBinding: 'parentView.src',
        viewName: 'embed'        
    }),
    src: null,
    srcChanged: function() {        
        this.get('embed').rerender();
    }.observes('src')
});
```

The template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="video">    
    {{view view.embedView}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="embed">    
  <object width="640" height="390"> 
    <param name="movie" {{bindAttr src="view.src"}} ></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
    <param name="playerapiid" value="main"></param>
    <embed {{bindAttr src="view.src"}} type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" width="640" height="390"></embed>
  </object>
</script>
```

Usage:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="your-template">
    ...
    {{view App.VideoView srcBinding="currentSource"}}
    ...
</script>
```

I created a live demo showing this working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/KZxgp/)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the src on an embed object won't cause the embed object to reload.  It's only used when initializing the embed object.  You'd need to replace the entire thing, I'd suggest creating a component/view and swapping out views instead of the src values.

Comment: I get what you are saying but I'm not clear on the details of how to do that. If I have a view how would I go about swapping the new view for the old view in the layout?